# show text value of html &copy; entity in input type=text?

Tags: json, html-entities

I'm loading a value from a json file which contains a copyright character. It's stored in the json as a html entity - `&copy;` which renders ©.

Handlebars is rendering a file editor for me in such a way that if the string is long it gets made into a textarea, and if it's short then it becomes a text input box instead. When rendered to a `<textarea>` the value is shown as its string version - something like `&copy; 2013 blah foo inc`, whereas if the value is written to a `<input type='text'>` value, then the browser renders it as its entity equivalent, no the string itself. I can't figure out how to make the text value of the entity itself appear, not its interpreted shape.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand that you want to convert html entity name (`&copy;`) into it's character (©) in input type `text`/`textarea`.

```
var content = "&copy; 2014 blah foo inc";
var copyright = $('<div>').html('&copy;').text();
var encoded = content.replace(/&copy;/g, copyright);
alert(encoded); // or $('#input_id').val(encoded);
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to change `&copy;` into `&amp;copy;`. When displayed `&amp;` turns into `&`.

The question doesn't specify the language, but in JavaScript you'd do

```
var content = "&copy; 2013 blah foo inc";
var encoded = content.replace( /&/g, '&amp;' );
```

Comment: Ok, so I'd have to modify Handlebars to do this or write an explicit value conversion helper to do so, but only in the case when being read from an `input type=text`, since the above wouldn't apply when the value is inside a textarea.. Hmm, not ideal, remotely. The value gets read back from the field using jQuery, might have to look at re-conversion after that point.