# Show jQuery slider value with &deg and 1 decimal place

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. How to make the value in 1 decimal place in a jQuery slider? eg. 25-> 25.0
2. How to show ºC or ºF in `.val()`, it just show "&deg" instead of the symbol?

Thank you!!!!

Here is my code:

```
<script>
    function createSlider(unit,temp){
var x;

if (unit=="C"){
x= $("#slider").slider({
value: temp,
min: 5,
max: 35,
step:0.5,
slide: function( event, ui ) {$( "#amount" ).val( ui.value+"&degC");}} );

$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" )+"&degC");
}
else{
x= $("#slider").slider({
// orientation: "vertical",
value: temp,
min: 41,
max: 95,
step:1,
slide: function( event, ui ) {$( "#amount" ).val( ui.value+"&degF");}} );

$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" )+"&degF");

}
return x;
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0;">
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Comment: Low hanging typo fruit, `&deg` should be `&deg;`

Comment: Thanks! but it just show &deg; not the º ~

Answer (score 1):

First we get the string value from the slider/textbox.

```
var str = $( "#amount" ).val();
```

To display a number with one decimal, convert it to a string and append a `.0`.

```
//if number does not have a period
if(str.indexOf('.') === -1)
{
  //then append '.0', converting it to a string
  str += '.0';
}
```

If we then want to append a degrees sign, we need to use a somewhat hack-y method. I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18457589/show-text-value-of-html-copy-entity-in-input-type-text) and have modified it to made it (hopefully) easier to use.

```
//create a div (as Evan noted, you should have a semicolon)
$('body').append("<div id='foo'>&deg;</div>");
//get div contents and delete div
var degree = $('#foo').text();
$('#foo').remove();
//replace the degree entity with the actual entity
str += '&deg;';
str.replace(/&deg;/g, degree);
```

Then we put the string back in the textbox.

```
$( "#amount" ).val(str);
```

Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this:

```
$("#amount").val($("#slider").slider("value")+"º");
```